# Model Derivative + new directToS3 + convert to SVF2 silent fail

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I have some buckets to which I have uploaded a few AutoCAD drawings.  I have converted to using the directToS3 approach to uploading files, and I can see the URNs of those files in the OSS bucket.  However, when I try to convert the file to SVF or SVF2, passing the bucketID and the URN to the file in the bucket, the files aren't translating to SVF and it just sort of fails silently.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("oss/uploadObject")]
public async Task<dynamic> UploadObject([FromForm]UploadFile input)
{
    // save the file on the server
    var uploadFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Uploads");
    if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);
    
    var fileSavePath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, Path.GetFileName(input.fileToUpload.FileName));

    dynamic uploadedObj;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileSavePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        await input.fileToUpload.CopyToAsync(stream);
        uploadedObj = await BinarytransferClient.UploadToBucket(    input.bucketKey,
                                                                    Path.GetFileName(input.fileToUpload.FileName),
                                                                    stream);
    }

    // cleanup, don't leave the binary on the server
    System.IO.File.Delete(fileSavePath);
    return uploadedObj;
}
```

File upload is handled via the forge-DirectToS3/BinaryTransferClient found at [this URL](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-directToS3/blob/net6.0/BinarytransferClient.cs), with my only change being how the token is passed since I had my own library already.  Querying the OSS buckets after upload shows the following result:

```
[
  {
    "id": "weuwb5gtwqzvqiykmpvhh8fj2zhslnfk-test1",
    "text": "test1",
    "type": "bucket",
    "hasChildren": true,
    "drawings": [
      {
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d2V1d2I1Z3R3cXp2cWl5a21wdmhoOGZqMnpoc2xuZmstdGVzdDEvNjExNTEwLmR3Zw==",
        "text": "611510.dwg",
        "type": "drawing",
        "hasChildren": false,
        "drawings": null,
        "project": null
      }
    ],
    "project": null
  },
  {
    "id": "weuwb5gtwqzvqiykmpvhh8fj2zhslnfk-test2",
    "text": "test2",
    "type": "bucket",
    "hasChildren": true,
    "drawings": [
      {
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d2V1d2I1Z3R3cXp2cWl5a21wdmhoOGZqMnpoc2xuZmstdGVzdDIvNjA1NzAyLmR3Zw==",
        "text": "605702.dwg",
        "type": "drawing",
        "hasChildren": false,
        "drawings": null,
        "project": null
      }
    ],
    "project": null
  },
  {
    "id": "weuwb5gtwqzvqiykmpvhh8fj2zhslnfk-test4",
    "text": "test4",
    "type": "bucket",
    "hasChildren": true,
    "drawings": [
      {
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d2V1d2I1Z3R3cXp2cWl5a21wdmhoOGZqMnpoc2xuZmstdGVzdDQvODgxMTYuZHdn",
        "text": "88116.dwg",
        "type": "drawing",
        "hasChildren": false,
        "drawings": null,
        "project": null
      }
    ],
    "project": null
  },
  {
    "id": "weuwb5gtwqzvqiykmpvhh8fj2zhslnfk638009921667451964-test3",
    "text": "weuwb5gtwqzvqiykmpvhh8fj2zhslnfk638009921667451964-test3",
    "type": "bucket",
    "hasChildren": true,
    "drawings": [
      {
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6d2V1d2I1Z3R3cXp2cWl5a21wdmhoOGZqMnpoc2xuZms2MzgwMDk5MjE2Njc0NTE5NjQtdGVzdDMvNjExNTEwLmR3Zw==",
        "text": "611510.dwg",
        "type": "drawing",
        "hasChildren": false,
        "drawings": null,
        "project": null
      }
    ],
    "project": null
  }
]
```

Finally, the transform code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("modelderivative/TranslateObject")]
public async Task<dynamic> TranslateObject([FromBody] TranslateObjectModel objModel)
{
    dynamic oauth = await OAuthController.GetInternalAsync();

    // prepare the payload
    List<JobPayloadItem> outputs = new List<JobPayloadItem>()
    {
        new JobPayloadItem(
            JobPayloadItem.TypeEnum.Svf2,
            new List<JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum>()
            {
                JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._2d,
                JobPayloadItem.ViewsEnum._3d
            })
    };
    JobPayload job;
    job = new JobPayload(new JobPayloadInput(objModel.objectName), new JobPayloadOutput(outputs));

    // start the translation
    DerivativesApi derivative = new DerivativesApi();
    derivative.Configuration.AccessToken = oauth.access_token;
    dynamic jobPosted = await derivative.TranslateAsync(job, true);
    return jobPosted;
}

/// <summary>
/// Model for TranslateObject method
/// </summary>
public class TranslateObjectModel
{
    public string bucketKey { get; set; }
    public string objectName { get; set; }
}
```

Passing any of the bucketKey, objectID combinations above results in, well, nothing.  I get success from the backend, but I have no actual derivative, or if I do I don't know what the URL is.  What exactly am I missing?  Maybe I need to make another call to get a different URN for the SVF from some other location/API call?

Comment: More information, looks like maybe my upload is trashing the file.

```
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741831",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                "1": {
                    "type": "error",
                    "code": "AutoCAD-InvalidFile",
                    "message": "Sorry, the drawing file is invalid and cannot be viewed. \n- Please try to recover the file in AutoCAD, and upload it again to view."

Answer (score 0):

When translation of manually uploaded files fails, it helps to (1) confirm that the byte size of the uploaded object matches the size of the original file, and (2) download the uploaded file and check if the contents are correct.

Also, please note that our SDKs now contain the direct-s3 upload/download functionality, so you can use it from there: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-upload-and-download-sdks.